# PowerPivot: Function for distance between two points Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, spreadsheet, powerpivot

I am currently using powerpivot and I added a column to create a calculated field for all rows. The purpose of the function is to find the distance between two zip codes by takin their Latitude and Longitude; this function always works in excel worksheets but when I attempt to use the same function in power query, it does not work. The reason why I'm using power query for this function is because the data set is over 4,000,000 rows...

I'm using the function below and it returns as "#ERROR"

[image: PowerQuery view]

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-'Origin vs Destination w PKG'[Latitude]))*COS(RADIANS(90-'Origin vs Destination w PKG'[DLatitude]))+SIN(RADIANS(90-'Origin vs Destination w PKG'[Latitude]))*SIN(RADIANS(90-'Origin vs Destination w PKG'[DLatitude]))*COS(RADIANS('Origin vs Destination w PKG'[Longitude]-'Origin vs Destination w PKG'[DLongitude])))*3958.8
```

Above is the function. Does anyone know how to get the distance function between two coordinates to work in PowerPivot?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table1 has 4 columns [Latitude_1], [Longitude_1], [Latitude_2], [Longitude_2] and the coordinates are in decimal [38.892456, -74.0247852] then code below generates the distance between the locations in miles (change 3959 to 6371 for kilometers) using the formula:

=ACOS(SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1))*3959

which in powerquery code is:

```
= Number.Acos(Number.Sin(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Sin(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) + Number.Cos(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos( ([Longitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI-([Longitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI)) * 3959)
```

full code sample:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "DistanceMiles", each Number.Acos(Number.Sin(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Sin(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) + Number.Cos(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos( ([Longitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI-([Longitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI)) * 3959),
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it's for powerquery and not power BI

Comment: That sample code is powerquery M code, so not sure what the issue is